# Remove active class from elements on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify the w3schools accordion so that it closes all panels before opening the clicked panel:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-trigger");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    acc.classList.remove("active"); //This is the line I've added
    this.classList.add("active"); //Changed to add from toggle
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
});
}
```

My modification doesn't work - I get

> acc.classList is undefined

I'm familiar with jQuery syntax, but I don't understand what else I need to do here in JS. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: `acc` is an array.  Note how the code already loops over that array.  If you want to perform an operation on each element in that array, you'd want to loop over it as well.

Comment: `acc` refers to an `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `classList` property.